# Read nested yaml values with out passing in the root object

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have the following yaml

```
John:
  surname: Smith
  age: 25
  verified: true
James:
  surname: Will
  age: 30
  verified: false
```

I am able to read the key value pairs when i pass the root object (John/James) to my function. Would it be possible to return only the object that has verified = true. So read all yaml values and return the whole John object because verified = true.

I am using snake yml

Comment: This question boils down to „is it possible to manipulate/process in-memory data“ which is obviously true. Can you be more specific about the problem you have with it?

Comment: @flyx the problem i am having is returning the parent objects which contain verified = true.

Comment: Well if that's all: `return root.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getValue().verified).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));`